# PHP json_decode notation issue

Tags: php, json

I am having an issue dealing with the notation used in a JSON file I am trying parse. Some of the nodes have . (periods) in the names which escapes object-notation 
`($json = $article->rssFeed.url;)`

How would I go about selecting the nodes. Do I need to str_replace the .(periods), or is there some other notation I can use? Here is a snippet of the JSON:

```
"docs": [{"rssFeed.type": "news", "rssFeed.url": "http://www.example.com/",  "score": 1.0 }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use braces around the name to access the property:

```
<?php

$o = json_decode('{"docs": [{"rssFeed.type": "news", "rssFeed.url": "http://www.example.com/",  "score": 1.0 }]}');

var_dump($o->docs[0]->{'rssFeed.url'});
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

@eWolf: you are still right, php is almost like javascript as its C like nature.

```
$object = json_decode('{"docs": [{"rssFeed.type": "news", 
                                  "rssFeed.url": "http://www.example.com/",
                                  "score": 1.0 }]}', TRUE);
```

**Note:** the 2nd argument to `json_decode()`, `TRUE`. It forces the function to return an associative array.

Now `$object['rssFeed.type']` can be used.